# Secure login page and user session

Tags: session, authentication, security

My first question is about standard steps to take in order to provide secure login page. Two things I am familiar with is putting password field to protect against someone watching over out shoulder, as well as transmitting data over https. Are there any other things one should include to have a fully secure login site?

Furthermore, once we log in, how is the session maintained i.e. when the user clicks sth our server knows that it should again generate user-based content? Considering whe are logged in, do we still need to maintain https and other security measures?

Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of things one can do to make a site more secure, but even if you did all of them, you have no guarantee that your site is "fully" secure.

For instance, if you're storing user login information in a database: did you put in protection against SQL injection? If your login page also contains a registration form: do you have protection against XSS exploits? Are there minimum requirements that the passwords must meet, or can users make their own (often very bad and easy to guess) passwords? There are some matters you can take into your own hands, but there are always things that, unfortunately, you won't think to protect against (because no one would've thought of them) until they're actually exploited. There are innumerable routes of attack for a site, and an equal amount of ways to protect against them, and it would take me far too long to delve into all of them (not that I'm all that security-savvy myself).

As the other answers have pointed out, sessions are maintained by a session ID, which is stored in a cookie on the client's side. When a session is started, the ID is generated; this ID is then used by the client's browser to identify data stored on the server side as belonging to that browser. To prevent this ID from being stolen, the connection should be encrypted using HTTPS; however, something to keep note of is that if you have any references to external resources in your page (e.g.: an image from another site, a script from another site, etc.), the connection will only be *partially* encrypted (namely, the parts that aren't external resources). This is less secure than full encryption for obvious reasons; to prevent this, I download all external resources into the local directory whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid one could write a book about it...

Addressing just the session question: session is usually maintained by some cookie that is sent with each consecutive request. And as information whether user is logged on not is based on the session cookie (or standalone user cookie) then the stolen cookie can be used to impersonate login. Therefore you would need to maintain https connection for the rest of the session (to protect the cookie) or at least take some minor security precautions (such as verify if session comes from the same IP address as before).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, password fields and https are definitely good approaches to the login.
I can't think of anything else to do right now either, except for maybe a Captcha, to make sure that it's not a robot script, trying to guess passwords.

Regarding the session management:
There is the '$_SESSION' variable, that is unique to every connection and gets maintained by PHP automatically, AFTER you called 'session_start();' at the beginning of the script.

This command is very important, otherwise $_SESSION will be empty at all times...if I'm not mistaken, it asks the browser for identification information (a SessionID or something of the likes), and then matches the stored information to that SessionID.

You use this session variable, like any other Superglobal.

```
$_SESSION['ID'] = $ID;
$_SESSION['AccessRights'] = $AR;
```

and so on.
The actual session data is stored at server side exclusively and cannot be altered from anything but the PHP script. Store everything you need to know about the user in $_SESSION and you should be fine.

Regarding the 'keeping up HTTPS': That should not be necessary, simply because all 'crucial data' has already been transferred.

Mind you though, once you're dealing with sensitive, or personal data (like changing password or anything the likes), you may want to go back to HTTPS again.
From experience, however, the actual overhead of HTTPS is rather minor in todays systems, and unless you're expecting a LOT of traffic, it's never a bad idea to keep it 'on'.

Now, I may be wrong concerning this issue, but that's my opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

as @Kuba said  - it's a huge topic. sessions fixation, session storing, protecting cookies, password security, response time to invalid login, accessing login page in non-secured way, XSS, sql injection and probably thousand more of which i have no idea.

my advice: don't do it on your own. there are plenty of security frameworks for every possible language. pick one, read their howto page and just use it. it will help you with most common tasks. but security of application does not end on login page. whole application should be secured written properly to be secured.